# How to find out if the administrator has really installed my facebook Canvas APP

Tags: facebook, installation

I'm developing an application that will allow users to dynamically load content on their Facebook pages.
The problem is that when they set up their application and press "Install" button, I save their settings in a database and redirect them to: `http://www.facebook.com/add.php?api_key=<MY_APP_KEY>&pages=1&page=....."`

After redirect, there are two options: "ADD Application" or Leave this app.

Is there any way that I can track whether the user has pressed the "ADD" button? For example if I can redirect the user after he press "Add this app" button, I'll be able to confirm that the user has really installed my application. After all, the user can hit "Leave", "navigate away of this page" or even "Close" his browser....